# Logcat isn't showing Log.i() messages

Tags: android, android-studio

It works the first time, but whenever I add a new line of code and run the Android emulator, the logcat doesn't show anything.

Code for when the button is clicked:

```
 public void clickFunction(View view)
    {
        EditText nameeEditText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEditText);
        Log.i("info", "it worked !");

        Log.i("Values", nameeEditText.getText().toString());
    }
```

Comment: I am sorry, this part is not clear, "but when ever add a new line of code".

Comment: Check the drop downs on the logcat, make sure you are not on a dead session and that you have verbose or info selected. Also, it would help to have your tag as something like "clickFun-info" so if you filter by clickFun, you can see all the logs from this method.